# Update Table using Datagridview in VB.Net and MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hello Everyone Good Afternoon.

I have a table in MySQL and I used to Show it using Datagridview and this is what it looks like

```
Item Name       Qty
Apple            0
Mango            0
```

1. I will click Export button and what happens next is that the Data in Datagridview will Extract into an excel sheet same as the Illustration above.
2. I will edit the Extracted Excel Data and I will put anything I want but for now here is the Example I will do.

   ```
   Item Name    Qty
   Apple         100
   Mango         100
   ```
3. I will click the Import Button and the excel will overwrite the Data in Datagridview.

My question here is that How can I update the changes happened in datagridview in Mysql Database using the RefID in Textbox1?

I hope you all get It, Im Using VB.Net and Mysql

TY

```
This is my code of Importing

 Dim conn As OleDbConnection
        Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dts As DataSet
        Dim excel As String
        Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

        If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            MsgBox("This will Overwrite your Current Data Proceed?")
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName

            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sheet1$]"
            conn.Close()
        End If
        With DataGridView1
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Item Code"
            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Description"
            .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Delivery Date"
            .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Stock On-Hand"
            .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Ordering Level"
            .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Order Qty"
            .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Approved Qty"
            .Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "UOM"
            .Columns(8).HeaderCell.Value = "Unit Price"
            .Columns(9).HeaderCell.Value = "Total"
            .Columns(10).HeaderCell.Value = "Remarks"
        End With
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Width = 70
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Width = 180
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Width = 70
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Width = 70
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).Width = 70
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).Width = 70
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).Width = 70
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(7).Width = 61
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(8).Width = 76
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(9).Width = 86
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(10).Width = 125
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            row.Cells("Total").Value = row.Cells("Order Qty").Value * row.Cells("Unit Price").Value
        Next

        Dim total As Integer = 0
        If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then
            For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                total += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(9).Value)
            Next
            TextBox7.Text = total
        End If
```

Comment: If I get it correctly this process leaves you without any trace of the change made in Excel so your only option is to loop over each row of your grid and execute an Update query for each Item Name (and if there are new items then you have the added problem to discover which items are new to insert them instead of updating)

Comment: First of all Sir TY for the Fast Respond to my Question, Yes Sir your Right you get my Logic and Question Correctly and I think the best way to do is do a loop to each row with an additional update command. About the adding new item, forget about that sir because I already create a seperate function for that. I hope sir you can help TY

Comment: What do you think Sir? What can I do to this?

Comment: When you import from excel you have probably some code that could be used to update the MySql database. You need to search the site on how to execute an Update query against MySql while looping over the data that you are importing. Another approach could be looping over the DataGridView rows and for each row execute the same update logic. Sorry but I can't write a whole program for you. Just try something yourself and then update this question with your attempt if it fails.